# I am scraping rightmove scraper websites but raise this error in my code

Tags: python, scrapy

This is my code:

```
#packages
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
from scrapy.selector import Selector
import json
import urllib
import datetime
import re

#sold houses class
class soldhouses(scrapy.Spider):
      #scraper name
      name = 'rightmove2'
      #base url 
      base_url = 'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/house-prices/CR0.html?' 
      
      #page index
      page_index = 0
      
      #string query parameters
      params = {
         'country': 'england',
         'locationIdentifier': '',
         'searchLocation': '',
         'referrer' : 'landingPage'
           }
      
      #headers
      headers = {
             'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/87.0.4280.66 Safari/537.36'
        }

       #custom setting
       #custom_settings = {
             #uncomment to set accordingly
             #"CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN":2,
             #"DOWNLOAD_TIMEOUT":1   #250 ms  of delay
        #    }     
         
      #on create 
      def __init__(self):

          #inti postcodes
          postcodes = ''
          
          # open "postcodes.json" 
          with open('postcodes.json', 'r') as json_file:
               for line in json_file.read():
                    postcodes += line
          #parse postcodes
          self.postcodes = json.loads(postcodes)

     
        

      #crawler's entry point
      def start_requests(self):
           #init filename
           filename = './output/Sold_houses_'+datetime.datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d-%H-%M')+'.jsonl'
           #postcodes count
           count = 0
           #init string query parameters
           for item in self.postcodes:
                self.page_index = 0
                self.params['locationIdendifier'] = item['locationId']
                self.params['searchLocation'] = item['postcode']
                url = self.base_url +urllib.parse.urlencode(self.params) 
                #print(url)
                yield scrapy.Request(url=url,headers=self.headers,meta={'postcode':item['postcode'],'filename':filename, 'count':count}, callback = self.parse_links)
                count +=1
                break


      def parse_links(self, res):

#         response = Selector(res= text)
#          with open('res.html', 'w' ) as f:
#                   f.write(res.text)
      
          postcode = res.meta.get('postcode')
          filename = res.meta.get('filename')
          count = res.meta.get('count')
#         #extract links
#         for card in res.css('div.propertyCard-content')
#         #debug selectors
          
#          content = ''
#          with open('res2.html', 'r' ) as f:
#              for line in f.read():
#                 content += line
#          res = Selector(text=content) 
          
         #extract basic features
          properties = ''.join([script for script in res.css("script::text").getall() if 'window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = {"results":' in script]) 
          properties = json.loads(properties.split('window.__PRELOADED_STATE__ = ')[-1])
          properties = properties['results']['properties'] 
          
          for property in properties:
            if property['detailUrl']: 
               prop_id = property['detailUrl'].split('?prop=')[-1].split('&')[0]
               links = 'https://www.rightmove.co.uk/property-for-sale/property-'+ prop_id +'.html'
             
               yield res.follow(url = property['detailUrl'],headers = self.headers, meta = {'property':properties,'postcode': postcode, 'filename':filename, 'count':count}, callback = self.parse_listing)
               break
      def parse_listing(self,res):
         
#          content = ''
#          with open('res.html', 'r' ) as f:
#              for line in f.read():
#                 content += line
#          res = Selector(text=content)    
          #extract features
          features = {
                   'id' : ''.join(re.findall('\d+',res.url.split('/')[-1])),
                   'url' : res.url,
                   'postcode' : res.meta.get('postcode'),
                   'title' : res.css('div.lef')
                                 .css('h1.fs-22::text')
                                  .get(),

                   'address' : res.css('div.cell')
                                   .css('address')
                                   .css('meta::attr(content)')
                                   .get(),
                           
                   'price' :   res.css('div.cell')
                                  .css('p.property-header-price')
                                  .css('strong::text')
                                  .get(),

                   'agent_link' : res.css('div.agent-details-display')
                                     .css('a::attr(href)')
                                     .get(),

                   'agent_name' : res.css('div.agent-details-display')
                                     .css('strong::text')
                                     .get(),

                   'agent_address' : res.css('div.agent-details-display')
                                     .css('address::text')
                                     .get(),

                   'agent_phone' : res.css('div.request-property-details')
                                      .css('strong::text')
                                      .get(),

                   'image_urls' : res.css('div.no-js-hidden')
                                     .css('img::attr(src)')
                                     .getall(),

                   'floor_area' : res.css('div.sect')
                                     .css('ul.list-style-square')
                                     .css('li::text')
                                     .get(),
                                
                   'key_features' : res.css('div.key-features')
                                       .css('ul.list-style-square')
                                       .css('li::text')
                                       .getall(),

                   'full_descriptions' : ''.join([feature.replace('\r').replace('\n').strip() for feature in 
                                            res.css('p[itemprop = "description"]::text')
                                            .getall() if feature != ''
                                                 ])
                     } 
           #extract price description
          # price_descr = res.css('div.cell').css('p.property-header-price').css('small::text').get(),
           #add text value to the price if available
           #features['price'] = price_descr.replace('\n').replace('\r').replace('\t')


          filename = res.meta.get('filename')
          with open(filename, 'a') as json_file:
                 json_file.write(json.dumps(features,indent = 2))

#main driver
if __name__ == '__main__':
    #run scrapers
    process = CrawlerProcess()
    process.crawl(soldhouses)
    process.start()   

     #soldhouses.parse_links(soldhouses,'')
```

the output is this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/defer.py", line 55, in mustbe_deferred
    result = f(*args, **kw)
File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/spidermw.py", line 60, in process_spider_input
    return scrape_func(response, request, spider)
File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/core/scraper.py", line 148, in call_spider
    warn_on_generator_with_return_value(spider, callback)
File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 202, in warn_on_generator_with_return_value
    if is_generator_with_return_value(callable):
File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 187, in is_generator_with_return_value
    tree = ast.parse(dedent(inspect.getsource(callable)))
File "/home/danish-khan/miniconda3/lib/python3.7/ast.py", line 35, in parse
    return compile(source, filename, mode, PyCF_ONLY_AST)
File "<unknown>", line 1
    def parse_links(self, res):
    ^
IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: Most likely you need to check your code indentation, making sure you count the spaces right, and don't mix spaces with tabs. Using an IDE like PyCharm or Visual Studio Code might make it easier to avoid these errors.